# Lay over at El Prat Barcelona, luggage and city tour

Tags: luggage, layovers, vueling, bcn

I am travelling back to my country from Venice, Italy next month, and I have a 8 hour lay over from 11h to 19h at El Prat airport in Barcelona, Spain.

**My First question** :  Do the airline company automatically transfer my luggage the next flight (since is the same company) Or do I have to grab my luggage and go again through customs and airport-security? if so, is there any luggage storage available?

**My Second question** : if the airline company automatically transfer my luggage the next flight (hopefully) is it possible to go outside the airport and what are the tourist attractions that I can visit during the 8 hour window?

I did some research and i found that there is three affordable options : Aérobus, public Bus, and the train, but it's my first time in Barcelona and I don't have a good estimate on the transportation time.

I have to mention also that the flight is assured by the same Company (Vueling) and I do have multi-entry Schengen visa.

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket?

Comment: yes, the both are in the same ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, Vueling transfer the luggage automatically for connecting flights according to [question 7 in their customer service FAQ](http://www.vueling.com/en/we-are-vueling/contact/faqs).

2) Yes, you should be able to get out of the airport and into the city. (You could do this even without a multi-entry Schengen visa, as you're not leaving Schengen in going from Italy to Spain.) All of those transport methods work, and they all take 30 - 40 minutes, so the best one depends on where you're going in the city. I would probably take the Aérobus as it goes directly from Terminal 1 (where Vueling operate from) to Plaza Cataluña (at the top of Las Ramblas, within easy walking distance of most of the sights).